# Missing artifact jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-api:jar:10.0.0

Tags: java, maven, jsf, jakarta-ee, mvn-repo

I've created new *Jakarta Faces* project and my purpose is using *Jakarta EE 10*.

I added this dependency to my `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But I've got error:

> Missing artifact jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-api:jar:10.0.0

My config is:

- *Java version "17" 2021-09-14 LTS*
- *Apache-Maven-3.8.2*
- *Eclipse IDE Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)*

and the project xml files:

- `faces-config.xml` **version="4.0"**
- `web.xml` **version="6.0"**
- `beans.xml` **version="4.0"**
- `persistence.xml` **version="3.1"**

What is the problem and how can I fix that?

I also searched *MVN Repository* for the latest version of `jakarta.jakartaee-api` and new version of that dependency is `9.1.0`. So, how can *Maven* find this version `10.0.0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Jakarta EE 10 was [released on Tuesday, May 31, 2022](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/jakarta-10).

---

Jakarta EE 10 is still in development, as of 2022-05.

Not yet ready for production use. So not yet listed in [Maven repositories](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.platform/jakarta.jakartaee-api).

See the [*Jakarta EE Platform Project*](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-platform/jakartaee10/JakartaEE10) page for current information.

Jakarta EE 10 brings the first major changes in many years. So much work is involved, with many decisions to be made, and many issues to work out. Patience is required.

## 2022-Q2 maybe

The **tentative** completion target for Jakarta EE 10 release is 2022-Q2. But this schedule is subject to change depending on the progress of the various components.

Unfortunately I cannot find Maven coordinates for early access to the platform API.

Comment: Based on this [link](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.jakartaee-platform/releases/10/plan) I thought I can use it! *Release Date: Thursday, March 31, 2022*

Comment: @MehdiRahimi End of March was the *planned* release date, but the end of May was the *actual* release date. I sent their webmaster a complaint of that page being out of date.